# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined for unit testing in mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write a unit test over my file routes.js using mocha and chai. I have defined a function in routes.js and has defined a test file in which my test case is there.

When i am running my test case, its showing the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

My code for test.js is

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var chai = require('chai');
var app = ('../api/smartAccount/identifyLoan/getDirectDebitTrans/routes');

describe("Unit testing for function", function(){
    it("Testing the function using mocha", function(done){
        var req = {
            queryString: 101
        };

        var test = app.getUser.get(req);
        expect(test).to.be.an('undefined');
        done();
    }); 
});
```

I am passing req as i am expecting req.queryString.id in my routes.js .

code of routes.js is

```
var config = require("../../../../serverConfig/config");

module.exports = {
   getUser: {
        get: function(req, parameters, environment) {

        var id = req.queryString.id;

         //functionality
         });
  }
 }
```

Please help where i am going wrong.

p.s get function is fetching data from DB but i havent mentioned the bd connection as i feel its of irrelevance here.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing scary here. You are missing the `require` keyword in `test.js`'s

`var app = ('../api/smartAccount/identifyLoan/getDirectDebitTrans/routes');`

**Hence;**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var chai = require('chai');
var app = require('../api/smartAccount/identifyLoan/getDirectDebitTrans/routes');
```

Will fix it.

Without the `require` keyword, variable `app` is just a string with value of `../api/smartAccount/identifyLoan/getDirectDebitTrans/routes'` and the code dies when it tries to access the non-existence `get` property. And this is evidently shown in your error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: thanx, it was a silly mistake missing on require, can you tell me how to pass this `req.queryString.id` in the test case?

Comment: @AjitejKaushik glad to help u but I don't understand what u mean by "passing `req.querystring.id` in the test case". Do u mean helping u to make the test go green,pass? Or passing the `req.querystring.id` to some where?

Comment: passing `req.queryString.id` to routes.js using test.js, what i mea is how to pass this param?

Comment: @AjitejKaushik sort of got what you meant after studying test.js and route.js for a bit. For route.js to be able to access the `id` property, you must first define it in the actual `req` object. To add the `id` property into the key `queryString`, you might want to consider doing this instead, `var req = { queryString: { id: 101 } }`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx!!, I will test and tell you.